# Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

```js
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['propsdata'],
    methods: {
      removeTodo(todoItem, index) {
        localStorage.removeItem(todoItem);
        this.todoItems.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li v-for = "(todoItem, index) in propsdata" class = "shadow">
        <i class = "checkBtn fas fa-check" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
        {{ todoItem }}
        <span class = "removeBtn" type = "button" @click = "removeTodo(todoItem, index)">
          <i class = "fas fa-trash" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>
```

Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined. These errors continue to occur. Please help me.

Comment: Where's todoItems defined?

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to `this.todoItems` in a component method, Vue expects the method to either come from `props` that were passed in, `data` that is defined with the component, or as a `computed` property.

From the template

```
<li v-for = "(todoItem, index) in propsdata" class = "shadow">
                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

it seems to me that what you're calling `todoItems` is either 1) `propsdata` or 2) a property inside `propsdata`. If we're looking at option 1), then rename either `propsdata` to `todoItems` or vice versa. If 2) then instead of referencing to `this.todoItems` do `this.propsdata.todoItems`

Comment: Did this Answer help?